# Show localized alphabetic index for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, alphabetical-sort

Is there a view to show localized alphabetic index for a UITableView? meaning if i change my system language the index titles should change too based the language chosen and tapping them should take me to respective section on a tableView.

I an relatively new to this, i hovered around S.O but only managed to see how to show them for a particular language say English but what if i change my system language i want my index title to change too.

This is what i have done -
I have an array of alphabets

```
@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",@"#"]
```

which i return back from

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return alphabetArray;
} 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
  // i go to respective index when i tap on some title
}
```

Now can someone please tell how do i localize this. eg Korean has this series

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, ㄱ, ㄴ, ㄷ, ㄹ, ㅁ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅇ, ㅈ, ㅊ, ㅋ, ㅌ, ㅍ, ㅎ, #
```

I know there is something like

```
[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation].sectionTitles.count .
```

which would give me the title count based on current locale, but can i really use it somehow. can someone please shed light on what can be done here??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `alphabetArray` should be created based on a displayed string (like the "title") of your models objects displayed in cells. Then show in Korean if needed, and it should be done that way, no?

Comment: `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is the correct class to use. But your app must be localized to whatever languages you wish to support. It's not enough to simply change the device language.

Comment: @maddy - Yes my app is localized, but how do i achieve what i mentioned above. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` is what you want.

For the section index titles you do:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation].sectionIndexTitles;
}
```

And then:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}
```

Assuming you want section headers matching the section index titles, and your data is broken up into proper sections to match, you do:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation].sectionTitles[section];
}
```